# How to define repeat and layer in vega-lite api

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vega-lite, vega

I have a data which looks something like this:

```
student_name,d,e
student1,0.1,0.7
student2,0.2,0.3
student3,0.3,0.4
student4,0.25,0.2
student5,0.4,0.15
student6,0.6,0.2
student7,0.15,0.5
student8,0.7,0.13
student9,0.56,0.22
student10,0.35,0.2
```

I want to visualize this data with [vega-lite-api](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite-api/) such that X-axis will have students and there will be two line charts each for column `d` and `e`. I tried something like [this](https://vizhub.com/Mahesha999/3f80d422fe574ccfba9550076d6faf62?edit=files&file=viz.js):

```
vl
  .markLine() 
  .encode(
    vl.x().fieldN('student_name').sort('y'), 
    vl.y().fieldQ('d'),
  );
```

This correctly shows column `d` values on y axis against students on x axis:

[image]

However, I am unable to guess how I can have column `e` values on y axis too.
I guess I need to repeat and layer, something like [this](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/repeat_layer.html):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "data/movies.json"
  },
  "repeat": {
    "layer": ["US Gross", "Worldwide Gross"]
  },
  "spec": {
    "mark": "line",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "bin": true,
        "field": "IMDB Rating",
        "type": "quantitative"
      },
      "y": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": {"repeat": "layer"},
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": "Mean of US and Worldwide Gross"
      },
      "color": {
        "datum": {"repeat": "layer"},
        "type": "nominal"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which outputs:

[image]

But I am unable to guess how can translate `repeat` and `layer` in above vega-lite grammar to vega-lite-api calls.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite-api/) you can use the `vl.repeat` and `vl.layer` methods to build `repeat` and `layer` objects.

You can then insert these into your spec with the `spec.repeat` method returned by [vl.encode()](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite-api/api/spec#repeat), and with the [y.field](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite-api/api/y#field) method.

Using your example, the following JS code

```js
vl
  .markLine()
  .encode(
    vl.x().fieldN('student_name').sort('y'), 
    vl.y().field(vl.repeat('layer')),
  ).repeat(
    vl.layer(["d", "e"])  
  )
```

will output this JSON:

```json
{
   "$schema":"https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
   "repeat":{
      "layer":[
         "d",
         "e"
      ]
   },
   "spec":{
      "mark":{
         "type":"line"
      },
      "encoding":{
         "x":{
            "field":"student_name",
            "type":"nominal",
            "sort":"y"
         },
         "y":{
            "field":{
               "repeat":"layer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[This notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/ca7eecd2d15584ff) will let you experiment with a live version of this code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I did it using `layer()` as can be seen in [this](https://observablehq.com/d/d227e0f85c5508fe#cell-3) notebook. Also changing `toSpec()` to `render()` in your notebook doesnt render the way I want.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! Yea, I was focused more on reproducing the JSON output rather than a particular graph.